# I would like to ask you how to replace the pictures in the smart layer with photoshop script?

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script

I would like to ask you how to replace the pictures in the smart layer with photoshop script?

Comment: You need to create a droplet in photoshop. This has nothing to do with JSX or javascript.

Comment: How should I operate?